# Avoid encoding of special characters in export to excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using phpexcel to export data in excel format and everything is working fine. But when I opens the downloaded file I seen that it encodes `(` and `)` to `&#40;` and `&#41;` and I want as it is i.e. `()`. I searched over this but I don't know how to do this.

Below is my code:

```
// Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Leads');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    //header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    if ($this->input->post('project_name') == 'all') 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Leads-'.date('d-m-Y H:i:s').'.xls"');
    else 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$project_name.'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: PHPExcel does nothing to convert cell values to HTML Entities: this must be happening elsewhere, perhaps in the code that you don't show

Comment: I run into this issue as well. Just wrap the subject strings in html_entity_decode()